# Java Regex for keyword appearance in either behind or after another keyword

Tags: java, regex

Regex always puzzled me. I thought I know enough, but when trying to make a pattern more robust, I always stumbled cases that I don't know

In java, say I have a word "BSD". And I would like to detect any sentence that have word "license" either before or after the word "BSD". The word "license" appearance is mandatory.
How do I do that in Java Regex?

This is as far as I know.

```
String REGEX = "(?i)(GNU)(\\s)+(license)?";
String contents1 = "This file is using GNU license.";
m = Pattern.compile(REGEX).matcher(contents1);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group());

String contents2 = "This  licensed using GNU version 2 .";
m = Pattern.compile(REGEX).matcher(contents2);
m.find(); 
System.out.println(m.group());
```

Comment: So, you want to match a string that has both `license` and `GNU` words in any order? E.g. `String REGEX = "^(?=.*license).*GNU";`?

Comment: Do you meant GNU?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/ZLekGX

Comment: Thanks its vert interesting... @WiktorStribiżew  . So let me try to rationalize your regex. Sentence start and look ahead for word anything followed by "license", then anything GNU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may check if a string contains both `license` and `GNU` (or `BSD`, whatever you use depends on your data and what you need to match) using

```
String REGEX = "^(?=.*license).*GNU";
String contents1 = "This  licensed using GNU version 2 .";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(REGEX).matcher(contents1);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found!");
}
```

See [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/ZLekGX).

The pattern matches:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*license)` - the positive lookahead that requires a sequence of literal chars `license` after any 0+ chars (not incl. line break chars if a dotall modifier is not used)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last
- `GNU` - a literal char sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a Regex expression to check for the combination "... GNU License ..." and "... License GNU ..." you can try something like this:

```
String a = "abc GNU License 213";
String b = "abc License GNU 123";

Pattern patternA = Pattern.compile("^.*(((GNU)\\s(License))|((License)\\s(GNU))).*$");
Matcher matcherA = patternA.matcher(a);

    if (matcherA.matches()) {
        System.out.println("matcherA matched");
    }

Pattern patternB = Pattern.compile("^.*(((GNU)\\s(License))|((License)\\s(GNU))).*$");
Matcher matcherB = patternB.matcher(b);

    if (matcherB.matches()) {
        System.out.println("matcherB matched");
    }
```

It matches any number of characters followed by either "GNU License" or "License GNU", followed by any number of characters.

Comment: Thank you @mind . But I think more "relaxed" is better.